# lftp can't download files used by another process

Tags: linux, lftp

I am trying to download logs from azure hosted linux app service. The old logs works nice, but when downloading current log the lftp said:

```
mget: Access failed: 550 The process cannot access the file
because it is being used by another process.
```

Any idea how to download log that is open for writing at the other end?

Comment: What OS is the server running?

Comment: azure linux app service

Comment: is that the same as Azure App Service on Linux?

Comment: yes, it's the name